# My question is on hold; please review and remove "on hold" from it

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question "https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/76220/48996" was put on hold yesterday. I edited it reduce the scope of the question, however, it is still on hold.

I would like some kind of feedback on what more I should do to improve the question. Or if the question is okay as it is currently, then I would like "on hold" to be removed from it.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

When you edited the question, it automatically entered the "reopen queue".  This allows users of the site that have sufficient reputation to look at the questions that were closed and vote to reopen them.

By the time that you posted this here, your question already had 2 reopen votes from members of the community.  It takes 5 reopen votes (or action from a moderator) to remove the "hold" status from a question.

I have reopened the question for you.

Comment: I went and closed it again. My reasoning is it is too broad and also is more of a list-style type question which is not a good fit for this format. My recommendation would be for the questions to be asked in chat.

Comment: A question that is closed as "too broad" because it asks a list of questions can also be fixed by limiting it to just one question.  If the answer to your single question doesn't fully satisfy your other questions, feel free to ask them as separate questions.

Comment: Just for future reference since the above question will be removed by the system automatically, the OP did narrow down his question [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76274/if-i-purchase-a-in-domain-name-but-do-not-live-in-india-could-i-risk-losing.).